# Examples of inner products on a polynomial vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

So far, I have only seen examples like the following:

$$
\langle p, q \rangle = \int_0^1 p(x)q(x)\ dx,
$$

where $p$ and $q$ are elements (polynomials) of a finite-dimensional polynomial vector space.

I'm wondering if there other kinds of inner products involving polynomials, without involving integrals or more interesting ones of the same kind.

Comment: $(p,q) = \sum_{k=0}^n p(k)q(k)$.

Comment: @copper.hat That's nice. Just need to make sure that have $n$ is greater than the degree of every polynomial in the space, otherwise the definiteness property is not satisfied for the polynomial with roots equal to $0, 1, \dots, n$.

Comment: Well, you could do something such as $(p,q) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty {1 \over 2^k} p({1 \over k}) q ({1 \over k})$, or $(p,q) = \int_0^\infty e^{-x} p(x)q(x) dx$. You mentioned that the vector space was finite dimensional, which is why I put the $n$ in the first comment. The latter two inner products will work in the space of all polynomials which is not finite dimensional.

Comment: @DoughnutPump Can you explain your point more clearly, please? Perhaps an example helps to clarify

Comment: @jublikon, consider the polynomial $p(x) = (x-0)(x-1)\cdots(x-n)$. This polynomial is nonzero, but with the inner product $(r, q) = \sum_{k=0}^n r(k)q(k)$ we have $(p, p) = 0$. This breaks definiteness property of inner products, that is, $(q, q) > 0$ for all $q \neq 0$. However, if we limit ourselves to polynomials of degree at most $n-1$, the inner product is well define, because such polynomials have at most $n-1$ distinct roots and thus, for least one $k$ in $0, 1, \dots, n$, $q(k)^2$ will be positive.

Answer (score 6):

Every finite-dimensional real vector space can be given an inner product by identifying the space with $\mathbb R^n$ by choosing a basis and transporting the canonical inner product.

For a finite-dimensional polynomial vector space, this gives 
$$
\langle p, q \rangle = p_0 q_0 + p_1 q_1 + \cdots + p_n q_n
$$
when you use the monomial basis $1, x, x^2, \dots, x^n$.
Here $p_i$ and $q_i$ are the coefficients of $p$ and $q$. (They are the coordinates with respect to the monomial basis.)

Answer (score 2):

Use the *Gramm-Schmidt process* to transform the basis $\{1,x,x^2\}$ of $\mathcal P_2$ into an orthonormal basis if inner product $p(0)q(0)+p(1)q(1)+p(2)q(2)$.

Answer (score 2):

The product $\langle p|q\rangle=\sum_n\alpha_n\beta_n$ can be viewed in a fancy way setting the map

$|p\rangle=\sum_n\alpha_nx^n\rightarrow\langle p|=\sum_n\frac{\alpha_n}{n!}\left.\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\right|_{x=0}$

Then,

$\langle p|q\rangle=\sum_{n,m}\frac{\alpha_n\beta_m}{n!}\underbrace{\left.\frac{d^nx^m}{dx^n}\right|_{x=0}}_{n!\delta_{n,m}}=\sum_n \alpha_n\beta_n$.

This is clearly a map between the vector space and its dual,

$x^n\rightarrow \frac{1}{n!}\left.\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\right|_{x=0}$ and thus the basis $\left\lbrace{1,x,x^2,...}\right\rbrace$ is orthonormal.

Comment: This inner product is also given by
$$\langle p | q \rangle = \int_0^1 p(e^{i2\pi t}) \overline{q(e^{i2\pi t})}\,dt.$$